# AngularJs OrderBy after push into an array in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, sql-order-by, push

I'm trying to sort an array after pushing a new element to it and show changes on my ng-repeat. It isn't working as expected, it looks like my scope is disconnected from the view.

I have a people array shown with a ng-repeater. Then a column header to sort the array by Last Name. Finally a button to add a new person and automatically sort the array by First Name and show it on the view.

This is my HTML code:

([I also have a fiddler here](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanarandaa/509xp9kf/20/))

Thanks!!

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller='myController'>
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Filter All" ng-click="filterAll()" />
      <input type="button" value="Add & Filter" ng-click="AddNFilter()" />
    </div><br/>
    <div><a href="" ng-click="orderByField='lname'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">Order by LName</a></div>
    <div ng-repeat="p in person | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort">
      {{p.name}} {{p.lname}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function ($scope, $filter) {
    var person = [{
            name: "Seimour"
            , lname: "Duncan"
        }
        , {
            name: "Engy"
            , lname: "Wook"
        }
        , {
            name: "Dame"
            , lname: "Eyola"
      }];
    $scope.person = person;
    $scope.filterAll = function () {
        alert('Before filter: ' + $scope.person[0].name);
        var filtered = $filter('orderBy')($scope.person, 'name');
        $scope.person = filtered;
        alert('After filter: ' + $scope.person[0].name);
    }
    $scope.AddNFilter = function () {
        var p = [{
            name: "Ayesha"
            , lname: "Shexper"
        }];
        alert('Length before adding: ' + $scope.person.length);
        $scope.person.push(p);
        var filtered = $filter('orderBy')($scope.person, 'name');
        $scope.person = filtered;
        alert('Length after adding: ' + $scope.person.length);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must convert your `p` variable into an object, instead of an array of objects to make your code work:

```
var p = {
  name: "Ayesha",
  lname: "Shexper"
};
```

Second, you don't need to sort again your object in the scope. It is enough if you change the variable that you pass to your orderBy filter in order to filter by the right property:

```
$scope.orderByField = 'name';
$scope.reverseSort = !$scope.reverseSort; // Optional! Do it if you want to reverse the sorting
```

You should do this in both, filterAll and AddNFilter functions to update the property that your filter by everytime you click any icon. You are doing it good when clicking `Order by LName`

I updated your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/509xp9kf/21/)